# CCC Forcing and $\omega_1$ conditions

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, forcing

I have a question about the proof of the Lemma 7.2 in the paper

> I. Juhász, P. Koszmider and L. Soukup,
>   *A first countable, initially $\omega_{1}$-compact but non-compact space*,
>   Topology and its Applications **156** (2009), 1863-1879.
>   doi:[10.1016/j.topol.2009.04.004](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2009.04.004)

I want to understand the argument in the highlighted part of the following proof:

> **Lemma 7.2.** *In* $V [\mathcal{G}]$, *for each set*
>   $A \in {\left[ \omega_{2} \times \mathbb{C} \right]}^{\omega_{1}}$
>   *there is* $\beta \in \omega_{2}$ *such that*
>   $\left| A \cap U (\beta) \right| = \omega_{1}$.
>
> **Proof.** Let $\dot{A}$ be a $P_{f}$-name for $A$ and assume that $p \in \mathcal{G}$ with
>   $$
> p \Vdash \dot{A} = \left\lbrace \dot{z}_{\xi} : \xi < \omega_{1} \right\rbrace \in
> {\left[ \omega_{2} \times \mathbb{C} \right]}^{\omega_{1}} .
> $$
>   We may assume that $p$ also forces that $\left\lbrace \dot{z}_{\xi} : \xi < \omega_{1} \right\rbrace$
>   is a one-one enumeration of $\dot{A}$.
>   For each $\xi < \omega_{1}$ we may pick $p_{\xi} \leqslant p$ and $\alpha_{\xi} \in \omega_{2}$
>   with $\alpha_{\xi} \in a_{p_{\xi}}$ such that
>   $p_{\xi} \Vdash \dot{z}_{\xi} = \left\langle \alpha_{\xi} , \dot{x}_{\xi} \right\rangle$.
>   Let $\sup \left\lbrace \alpha_{\xi} : \xi < \omega_{1} \right\rbrace < \beta < \omega_{2}$.
>   By Lemma 7.1 for each $\xi < \omega_{1}$ there is a condition $q_{\xi} \leqslant p_{\xi}$
>   such that $\alpha_{\xi} \in h_{q_{\xi}} (\beta , 0)$, hence
>   $q_{\xi} \Vdash \dot{z}_{\xi} \in U (\beta)$.
>   **But $P_{f}$ satisfies CCC, so there is $q \in \mathcal{G}$ such that
>   $q \Vdash \left| \{ \xi \in \omega_{1} : q_{\xi} \in \mathcal{G} \} \right| = \omega_{1}$.**
>   Clearly, then $q \Vdash | \dot{A} \cap U (\beta) | = \omega_{1}$. $\square$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there were no such $q$, then it would be forced, by all conditions, that $\{\xi\in\omega_1:q_\xi\in\mathcal G\}$ is countable and therefore bounded below $\omega_1$.  Consider a maximal antichain of conditions that force specific values ($\check\gamma$) for the bound.  Since the antichain is countable, there are only countably many $\gamma$'s involved here, so there's a countable upper bound $\delta$ for all of them.  But then, if $\delta<\xi<\omega_1$, no condition can force $q_\xi\in\mathcal G$, which is absurd as $q_\xi$ forces this.